# AJAX calls to a controller action are not consistent

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form in ASP.NET MVC4 with one textbox and two buttons.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Steps", "Technique", new 
                      { step = ViewBag.step + 1, 
                         techniqueId = @Model.Krok.TechniqueId
                      },
                      FormMethod.Post,
                      new { id = "theForm" })
       )
 { 
    <label>@Model.Krok.Text</label>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Krok.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Krok.Poradi)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Krok.TechniqueId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
    if (@Model.Krok.HasMultipleAnswers)

    <input type="button" value="Add One More" id="AddButton" />

    <input type="submit" value="Next Step" id="submit_btn" />
}
<input type="button" value="Add One More" id="add_btn" />
<input type="submit" value="Next Step" id="submit_btn" />
```

The first button creates one more textbox using jQuery and the second button processes all the textboxes and stores the data to SQL.

```
$("#add_btn").click(function () {
        $("#theForm").append("<br /><label> one more attribute</label>")
                     .append("<input type = 'Text' id='_addText' />");
    });
```

As soon as the button that processes the form is clicked, jQuery handles this event and send the data to a controller action.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function () {
        alert("clicked!")
        var options = {};
        options.url = "/Technique/AjaxTest";
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            answer: $("#_addText").val()
        });
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.error = function (jqXHR, status, err) { alert(status); };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
```

But this controller action is not rendering consistently, meaning that sometimes the action is fired and processes as it has to process, but another time the action is not even called (I was using debugger). Why it is not working consistently?

Comment: Debug the network traffic in your browser. When your action should be called.. does the browser actually send the request? Do you have custom routes?

Comment: Sorry, by debuging the traffic you mean to use something like wireshark? Or are there any embedded debugers for instance in Chrome?  No, I have changed slightly my routes.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is suppose to work.  Input elements should have a unique ID, but it looks like you add multiple inputs with the same ID `_addText`.

Comment: Erik makes a good point (I didn't quite look that closely at the code). Still, yes, all browsers come with a Network tab in their developer tools that let you see the requests it sends. You don't need anything more low-level than that to debug this.

Comment: Yeah I know that, for now I am just adding only one input element, I will change it latter. I just want my controller action to work every time the button is clicked.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I just tried to see the network traffic, and it showed that sometimes this ajax requests are cancelled.

Comment: Have you looked at the answer given below? It is the most likely cause of your issue (that is, the browser cancels the post because it is responding to a submit click).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Sorry, may I ask to make things clear for me. The submit button cancels the post to a contoller action because it is just posting the data to another controller before jQuery sent the data to a contoller action? I tried to change the type of the button, but it turned out that I need this button to send POST requests.. Probably I should change the logic of my application and I will do this, but for now I am just curious why sometimes it works fine and another times it is not working.. Sorry for being intrusive.

Comment: The browser is already going to post.. because you have a submit button inside a form. This is default browser behaviour. You're also attempting to post yourself.. one has to win that battle..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the default action of the button click i.e. the HTTP POST submission of  the form, is being suppressed, and this is possibly occurring before the jQuery acts.

If you have

```
$("#submit_btn").click(handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert("clicked");
    ......
}
```

you will then have the HTTP POST out of the way.

Comment: Although an easier answer is to just replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips i agree use a simple button and you will figure out in an easier way